# How does jQuery grab elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am using jQuery to select all anchor tags that start with a certain prefix and then call a function for each:

```
$('a[id^="lblMyLabel"]').each(function() {
        doSomething(this.id);
});
```

and inside of doSomething I make an ajax call to fetch some data.  I was assuming that jQuery would scan the page from top to bottom grabbing all the anchor tags starting with lblMyLabel and act on them in that order but the order seems to be random.  Does anyone know how this selection takes place?

**EDIT:** So I agree you guys are all right that it picks the items from top to bottom.  But if I stick a break point on the WebMethod responding to the ajax call it is not getting the ID's in that order.  How is that order determined?

Comment: I believe the order is sequential from top to bottom.

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=init that's a neat tool to view jquery source.

Comment: I believe you are talking from top to bottom as they appear in the DOM

Comment: Ajax requests are not guaranteed to complete in the order that you start them due to their asynchronous nature. Some may be returned by the server faster or slower than others.

Comment: This is really just me being curious so its not important.  And I agree that server will return some faster than others, I guess I was still assuming that the original call would still be done in a sequential order and therefore the break point would see them coming in that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, in a modern browser, jQuery uses

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[id^="lblMyLabel"]')
```

allowing the browser to do the work.

In all cases other than .prev like methods jquery returns elements in the order that they appear in the document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: and seems like it returns in _depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes_ which I suppose is sequential.

Comment: @Vega yes, that's "document order." http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#findelements

Comment: I think his comment was prior to me adding that line.

Answer (score 2):

The order of DOM elements in a jQuery object created like this (and thus the order that `.each()` is called) is sequential from top to bottom in the document, but if you're then doing a bunch of ajax calls at once, the responses from those ajax calls are not guaranteed in any specific order because that depends upon the processing time on your server for each response.

If you want to process the ajax responses in order, then you probably need to give each one of them some sort of sequence identifier, queue them all up and only process item N after you've already processed the ones before it.  The simplest way to do this is to just queue all the results in an array according to their original sequence number and then process all the results in order when they are all done.  There are more complicated ways to do it that will process N as soon as all the ones before have arrived and been processed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the # character when selecting CSS ids, as in the following example:

var messagePara = $('#message');

Comment: If you use the code that I am showing in my question it will grab every anchor tag in the document that has an ID that begins with whatever you put between the single quotes.  You do not need to use # in this situation.